# Date format conversion brings an unexpected empty space between the date parts

Tags: qgis, convert, date, formula

I always used the formula (below) in Python Calculator to convert the date format from Julian to Gregorian format. But,now a weird behaviour is happening and I am trying to figure out what is wrong in the processing. I am using QGIS 3.12 and after processing the formula no errors rises, but when I opened the new field in the table a little problem is detected. There is a empty space (4 spaces) between Year and Month parts of the date and I'm not able to identify this error and remove It. The new format date generated is "2016-***[space]***01-12 23:45" and the correct and expected result should be "2016-01-12 23:45".

Following the formula I'd used:

```
timestampparts=<Date_Time_Local>.split(' ')  
dateparts=timestampparts[0].split('-')  
timeparts=timestampparts[1].split(':')  
newdate='{0[2]}-{0[0]}-{0[1]} {1[0]}:{1[1]}'.format(dateparts, timeparts)  
value=newdate
```

And the output of conversion process:

[image: date conversion process]

There is something I can do to fix It?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/372851/edit) and include an example of `<Date_Time_Local>`.